# Как в плеере разместить картинку?

Tags: html, css, css3

Подскажите как в плеере разместить картинку?

```css
iframe {
  border: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<iframe class="subscribe-video" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/14352658?title=0&byline=0&portrait=0" width="500" height="305">
</iframe>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/duLahd1z/)

Comment: можно поверх плеера разместить картинку

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/4qeg98ja/

css

```
iframe{
  border: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
img{
  border: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.img-vm
{
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
}
```

html

```
<iframe class="subscribe-video" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/14352658?title=0&byline=0&portrait=0" width="500" height="305">
</iframe>
<div class="img-vm">
<img height="305" width="500" src="https://community.mypaint.org/uploads/default/optimized/1X/4699061a23256d40fa5081c23b7dc2ae03643605_1_690x481.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: Элементы управления плеера должны быть видны

Comment: можно просто сделать картинку по высоте меньше, но проблема в том что когда будут нажимать плей, картинка будет мешать. 
можно убирать верхний слой картинки, когда мышка будет стоять на нем.

Comment: Необходимо чтобы картинка находилась под элементами управления. Если в данном случае нет возможности её вставить, может есть способ подключения видео позволяющий это сделать. Например как тег video  с атрибутом poster, но необходим плеер Vimeo.

Comment: https://vimeo.com/blog/post/turn-any-video-frame-into-a-thumbnail